# How to Fit Recyler view items according to layout size in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using recycler to show 8 items in the list. However the number 8 is fixed.
I want to resize the items according to the size of the parent layout in which recycler view is given.
That means all 8 items should show in equal size and should fit into one screen view. No scrolling to be needed.

An Image for reference I have attached.
[image: RecyclerView]

My question is how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here maybe can be your reference, you can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` as your `layoutManager` and set your `spanCount` to 8 for making a grid with 8 items

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="8"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_recycler"
    tools:itemCount="8"/>
```

In your item view just make sure everything in your layout is match with the parent like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the result for the item layout

[image]

And this is the result that you expected, you also can validate your view using `Layout Validation` to make sure it is expected in any kind of size devices you want

[image]